# LLamar a un ActionResult desde Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Desde Jquery quiero llamar a un ActionResult de un controlador, pero no llega. Ese ActionResult no pertenece a ninguna vista, simplemente quiero que cambie un dato en BBDD. Como podria conseguirlo.

El error que deja la consola de javascript :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

Aqui dejo el código.

```
$(".abrirCorreo").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var miUrl = '@Url.Action("Confirmacion", "Correo")'
        $.ajax({
            url: miUrl,
            method: "post",
            data: id,
            success: function (response) {

            },
            async: true
        });


    })


 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Confirmacion(int idCorreo)
    {

        DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

            Correo correo = db.Correo.Where(a => a.IdCorreo == idCorreo).First();

            if (!correo.Leido)
            {
                correo.Leido = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View();


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partamos de la base que un ActionResult no se invoca, sino que es la respuesta. Lo que invocas es un `action` de un `controller`.

La definicion de ajax parece correcta pero no envias los datos de forma adecuada, que pasa si usas

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");

var params = { idCorreo: id };                  

$.ajax({
    url: miUrl,
    method: "post",
    data: params,
    success: function (response) {

    },
    async: true
});
```

tienes que armar el json de forma que el valor coincida con el del parametro del action, por eso `idCorreo`

Sino funciona de esa forma usa en el ajax

```
data: JSON.stringify(params),
```

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify)

Comment: muchas gracias :)